# Find latest date but earliest time

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I know how to find the latest or earliest date in a column. But, what I want to do is highlight in a column the latest date (dd-mm-yyyy) but the earliest time (hh:mm) of this date. I.e. out of the bottom column I wish to highlight 02/05/2017 06:14 and not 02/05/2017 07:18

```
26/04/2017 06:52
26/04/2017 07:15
26/04/2017 07:16
26/04/2017 07:16
26/04/2017 07:20
26/04/2017 07:20
26/04/2017 07:20
26/04/2017 07:22
26/04/2017 07:22
27/04/2017 06:36
27/04/2017 07:04
27/04/2017 07:14
27/04/2017 07:14
27/04/2017 07:20
27/04/2017 07:20
27/04/2017 07:21
27/04/2017 07:21
27/04/2017 07:21
27/04/2017 07:21
27/04/2017 07:28
27/04/2017 07:29
27/04/2017 07:29
27/04/2017 07:29
27/04/2017 07:33
27/04/2017 07:33
27/04/2017 07:42
27/04/2017 07:42
27/04/2017 07:42
28/04/2017 06:40
28/04/2017 07:13
28/04/2017 07:14
28/04/2017 07:16
28/04/2017 07:21
28/04/2017 07:21
28/04/2017 07:26
28/04/2017 07:32
28/04/2017 07:41
28/04/2017 07:41
28/04/2017 07:44
28/04/2017 07:46
28/04/2017 07:54
02/05/2017 06:14
02/05/2017 06:46
02/05/2017 07:13
02/05/2017 07:14
02/05/2017 07:18
```

Comment: How will you find the latest date in this range? put that info also here please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your data is in ColumnA (and sorted) please select ColumnA and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=A1=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(INT(MAX(A:A)),A:A)+1)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of formatting, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Comment: Good answer! I especially like `INT(MAX(AA))`

Comment: Awesome answer - Worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

`=SMALL(IF(A1:A91>MAX(IF(A1:A91>0;ROUNDDOWN(A1:A91;0)));A1:A91);1)`

where A1:A91 was the range I pasted values into. Enter the formula by pressing CTRL + ALT + ENTER (it is an array formula) and it will return the largest date with smallest time.

EDIT:
for clarification, you can put this into a separate cell and just compare source values with result of this cell in your conditional formatting setup.

Comment: Do you think this will  work for conditional formatting?? (highlighting cells)

Comment: You can put it into separate cell and just compare source values with result of this cell in your conditional formatting setup.